# Message: Illegal offset type at line 4761

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
        // Add emoji
        $country['emoji'] = self::getEmojiByAlpha2($country['alpha2']);

        $countriesByLanguage[$language][$countryKey] = $country;
    }

    self::$_countriesByLanguages = $countriesByLanguage;

    return self::$_countriesByLanguages[$language];
}

print $countriesByLanguage[$language][$countryKey] = $country;
```

trying to get country shortcode

Comment: Which line is 4761